# Windows 2003 Active Directory Integrated DNS zone not registering non-domain computers

Tags: windows-server-2003, domain-name-system, domain-controller

I'm not a networking guy by all means, I'm just a developer who dabbles enough to get into trouble and I'm there.  So bear with me... :)

At my office I have a Windows 2003 Domain Controller which also services DNS. On the domain I have a handful of computers and other misc. equipment/toys.  For the DNS I only created a Forward Lookup Zone for my domain (mydomain.com).  I run a lot of VM's so generally I have everything on the domain, however some of those VM's are not and only in a 'Workgroup'.  I also have another laptop which belongs to another domain (otherdomain.com) which is here 100% but I use it for other purposes and has to belong to the otherdomain.com.

With all that said, I have two questions:

1. I have found any computer not on mydomain.com does not register it's IP address even though 'Register this connections address in DNS' is set to in the 'Advanced TCP/IP Settings' for the nic.  Where have I messed this up?
2. On the laptop which is registered on otherdomain.com, when I do a nslookup for a computer on mydomain.com (e.g. nslookup devbox1) it appends otherdomain.com as the suffix (e.g. queries devbox1.otherdomain.com).  Same thing occurs if I use the fully qualified name.  In the 'Advanced TCP/IP Settings' for that nic, I can 'Append these DNS suffixes' of mydomain.com but I fear that will hose my DNS lookups when I VPN to otherdomain.com.  So what is the correct approach to resolve this issue?  Do I add both mydomain.com and otherdomain.com in that order?

Answer (score 2):

For #1 have you allowed Nonsecure and secure Dynamic Updates of DNS?  If not, only domain clients will be able to update DNS. This is set on the General tab of the DNs zone.  You should understand the implications before changing it.
If you use DHCP for all clients, you can configure the DHCP server to update DNS on the DNS tab of the scope settings.

For #2 your approach sounds right.  Remember you can change it back after testing.  Other than that, you can specify the full domain name and append a "." to prevent the appending of mydomain.com

Comment: Regarding #1, generally speaking, what would the implications be?

Comment: Any unauthenticated client can update DNS.  If the environment is controlled, you're probably OK.  If not, try the DHCP way first

Comment: Regarding #2, if I do an nslookup on yahoo.com there are three searches now which occur: yahoo.com.mydomain.com, yahoo.com.otherdomain.com and then yahoo.com.  Is that appropriate?

Comment: what happens if you do a nslookup on yahoo.com. ?

Comment: My last comment was wrong, yahoo.com. returns three correct A records.  So I think we're good there.  I did an "ipconfig /registerdns" to see if #1 worked but the event log return "Name resolution for the name LT-JWILLENER.otherdomain.com timed out after none of the configured DNS servers responded."